# Dynamic HTML includes an Angular 'ng-click' attribute that won't fire

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a twitter bootstrap popover that I fill with HTML dynamically.  In that HTML, is an unordered list full of li elements that contain `ng-click` attributes that target a method on my controller...

However, the li elements ng-click event doesn't fire.  Yet, I have a button that loads on page load with an ng-click attribute that fires perfectly.  But, in the dynamic HTML, the ng-click does not work.  I assume this is because the dynamic HTML cannot access `$scope` for some reason.  Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
            var popoverContent = '<ul class="list-unstyled">'
            cities.forEach(function(city, index){
                popoverContent = popoverContent + '<li class="town-listing" ng-click="selectAutocompleteCity('+ city.name +')"><span class="city-name">' + city.name + '</span></li>';
            });
            popoverContent = popoverContent + '</ul>';
            $('#town-search-field').popover({
                animation: true,
                html: true,
                content: '<div id="city-popover-inner" style="min-height:100px;width:250px;"></div>',
                placement: 'bottom',
                trigger: 'manual',

            });
```

Comment: If you "mess with the DOM" outside angular's scope, you need to tell angular to do its dirty checking: `$scope.$apply()`. I'd have to see the bigger context to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

From what little code you posted, I can tell you're going about angular all wrong. The jQuery way of doing things and the angular way of doing things are very different. Again, you didn't post much code, but I'm sure you'd be way better off putting whatever logic you have into a custom directive.